# Authenticating to a website using a node js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ssl, https

My overall goal is the following:

-> Get data from fabric.io (=crashlytics) into a geckoboard dashboard.

To my knowledge there is no API on crashlytics/fabric side, so I had the following idea:

Write a script in nodejs (because I know node js a bit, I'm no expert though) that would:

1. Open the html page where the data I want is
2. Find my data using htmlparser
3. Save that data into a google sheet
4. Make geckoboard read the google sheet and display the data

Step 4 is done already and I'm working on step 1 now.
Unfortunately I'm having a problem as the page is not publicly accessible, I need to authenticate using my user account.

I've reused some code that works just fine when doing GET/POST/PUT on some other websites' REST api, but it doesn't seem to work here as fabric is redirecting me to the login page.

However when I search the web for node auth, I find modules for people to create a server that will handle authentication, whereas I'm trying to use node to login to a website.

It's well possible that what I'm trying to achieve or the way I'm trying to do it don't make sense at all. But as I'm not skilled enough to realise that, I'd be happy if someone could confirm it to me. At least I'd know I'm looking into the wrong direction ;-)

Thanks for reading me

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var creds = require('./config/credentials.js');
var date = new Date();
var htmlpage = "";

var authorizationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(creds.login + ":" + creds.pwd).toString("base64");
var get_options = {
    hostname: "fabric.io",
    path: "/my-company-account/ios/apps/app.identifier/answers/stability",
    method: "GET",
    port: 443,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": authorizationHeader
    }
};

var get_req = https.request(get_options, function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        htmlpage += chunk;
    }); // end res.on 'data'

    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log(htmlpage);
        //tmp debug
        fs.writeFile('./logs/ac-ios_' + date.getTime() + '.html', htmlpage, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }); // end write html file

        /*var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
        parser.parseComplete(htmlpage);*/
    }); // end res.on 'end'
}); // end https.request

get_req.on("error", function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });

get_req.end();
```

Which gives me the following html:

```
<html>
<body>You are being <a href="https://fabric.io/login?redirect_url=%2Fwebedia-mobile%2Fios%2Fapps%2Fcom.allocine.applifrance%2Fanswers%2Fstability">redirected</a>.</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe that you've to send post request to login page and after that you've to use cookie or other auth token info to send other requests like getting the stability page etc. But I am not sure if that is possible since fabric.io doesn't have an api; https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-io-rest-api/30150 As I've tested it sends an authentication header to this page https://fabric.io/api/v2/session

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Indeed I logged into my browser and used the cookie into my get request and it worked. Unfortunately the website returns me an error that I should enable JS. I guess I'll have to use something like phantomJS to get my data. What a pain :p